# Determining existence of a subgroup of order $p$ of a $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups

Does a finite $p$-group (ie a group of order $p^n$ for some prime $p$ and some positive integer $n$, specifically for $n \geq 2$) necessarily have a subgroup of order $p$? How can one see this result?

Comment: This is Cauchy theorem.

Comment: Do you know where  I might find a relatively simple/easy proof of Cauchy's group theorem? I am finding some of the proofs online inaccessible to my level.

Comment: @math1337 Two routes are via the class equation (looking at the conjugacy classes of a group) or via the Sylow theorems. Both are covered in http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf, for example, which has efficient proofs eg at 4.13, remark 5.4 - and see the quotation at the head of p75. Essentially you need to count the right thing well. If it looks complicated, it really isn't when you get your head round it, and it is worth the time to do that. Cauchy is definitely a level or two above Lagrange in this context - and you will benefit from getting to that level by working at this.

Answer (score 1):

Every subgroup has an order which divides the order of the group (Lagrange). This applies in particular to the cyclic subgroup generated by a non-identity element $a$ - so $a$ has order $p^r$ for some $0\lt r\le n$.

Now consider $a^{p^{r-1}}$ which has order $p$ and generates a subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: How do you know that $ a^p^(r-1) $ will have an order of $p$? Looking at what you have types seems convincing but I have seen solutions to similar questions which use induction or more material such as conjugacy classes. Are such methods necessary?

Comment: @math1337 Suppose $a$ has order $k=np$ then $a^n$ has order $p$, bearing in mind that $k=np$ is the lowest power with $a^k=1$. Now apply this with $k=p^r=p\cdot p^{r-1}$.

Comment: @math1337 In the particular case of a $p$-group, the orders of cyclic subgroups are heavily constrained. In other cases it requires more work to show that there has to be a subgroup with order a multiple of a specific prime factor which divides the order of the group (eg Sylow theorems).

Comment: Ah, that a great deal of sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A $p$-group $P$ has subgroups of every possible order: An abelian group has subgroups of every possible order. Consider $Z(P)$. If $Z(P)=P$, then we're done. If not, then at least $Z(P)$ has subgroups of every possible order. Consider $P/Z(P)$, whose order is strictly smaller than that of $P$. (why?) Apply induction to show that $P$ has subgroups of every possible order.

Comment: When you say "of every possible order" I was initially taken aback. Can I assume that is another way of saying "of every order dividing the order of the ($p$-group $P$ / Abelian group)."

Comment: @StephenMeskin Yup. Subgroups of every possible order dividing the order of the group concerned.

Comment: Is it possible to do it this way without assume that $P$ is abelian?

Comment: Read it carefully. I never had this assumption. What if $Z(P)\neq P$?

Comment: Sorry, what is $Z(P)$, I am unfamiliar with it

Comment: Center of the group $P$. You should deal with the basics first if you're not familiar with them. $p$-groups is not one of the basics.